# Can I run a terminal on IOS with sandboxed filesystem (w/o jailbreak)?

Tags: ios, terminal, homebrew

Can I run a terminal app on IOS with a sandboxed filesystem (no jailbreak).  E.g. is there an app that allows me to locally install linux on an IOS device (without jailbreak)?

More precisely: I am not looking for an ssh client, but for a way to install locally on IOS e.g. something like homebrew, e.g. to use arbitrary programming languages or emacs or vim or latex or clojure or haskell or etc ;)

So, it would be totally fine, if such an app has its own unix-style file system and only commandline, i.e. no GUI.

Comment: I don't think that a sandboxed app that does what you asked for exists, and I think no one would spend their time making it. what you can do though is make your own app (an app that connects to a server and runs your commands or something like that)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to resurrect an old question. . .

I was actually browsing for info on a new iOS app that sort of does just what this question is asking about, emulates a Linux environment via a pretty slick terminal app.

It's called [iSH](https://ish.app/). Still in beta but I think you can get a Testflight invite right on the homepage.

It even has *pseudo* access to the Files app.

For instance, you can make a directory with `mkdir`, create a script with the terminal using any number of editors, and then open said script in the Files app like it were an iCloud text document in your TextEdit folder.

But, as far as I can tell, you *can not* move that script directly to Dropbox, or your TextEdit folder on iCloud.

You can, however, copy and share the text via the share extension.

Anyone else been screwing with this app?

Here's the [GitHub](https://github.com/tbodt/ish) link to the project, and they've got a Twitter and reddit, too.

A few screenshots of the app in action on an iPad with the Files app, and without:

[image: iSH]
[image: Files overview]
[image: splitscreen]

Answer (score 2):

Not really. There isn’t any sort of ssh / bash shell functionality exposed by Apple on iOS 11 or older.

Jailbreak is the most direct path to getting generic shell access to iOS.

I’ve taken to traveling with a small wifi router and raspberry pi / beaglebone so I can let iOS do iOS well and ssh over to a true Linux / Unix device when I need that local and not running in the cloud or a data center / back at home.